# Recursive function call in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question regarding the following (very weird) issue.

I have a parent component like this:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  
  const [myParam, setMyParam] = React.useState(1);
   
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Setting myParam to 0...');
      setMyParam(0);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent myparam={myParam}></ChildComponent>
    </div>
  )
}
```

From this parent component I pass the param `myParam` (with default value 1) to the child component as a prop.

Child component looks like this:

```
function ChildComponent(props) {

  const loop = () => {
  
    if(props.myparam) {                // DOES NOT DETECT PROP CHANGE PROPERLY!!!
      setTimeout(() => loop(), 1000)
    }
  }
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    if(props.myparam) {
      loop();
    }
    
  }, [props.myparam])
  
  return (
    <div>
      Loop demo
    </div>
  )
}
```

The initial value of `myparam` is 1 so the `loop` function starts its recursion.

Then, the parent component updates the prop after 3 seconds, and it is being properly detected in `useEffect()` hook in child component BUT the loop function does not detect the prop change and keeps running recursively.

The expected behavior, from my point of view, is that the recursive function (`loop()`) should stop its execution after the prop `myparam` gets the value 0 (changed from parent component) because in `loop()` function I have this IF statement:

```
    if(props.myparam) {                // DOES NOT DETECT PROP CHANGE PROPERLY!!!
      setTimeout(() => loop(), 1000)
    }
```

Any explanations for this strange behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try to remove the props.myparam from the useEffect dependency array and check what happens?

it changing it to 

````
React.useEffect(() => {
    
    if(props.myparam) {
      loop();
    }
    
  }, [])
````

solves the problem I have a theory to explain it.

Comment: `props` isn't mutable. On update, React essentially passes a new `props` object to the child component. The old `loop` function from previous render will still refer to the old `props` object in which the value of `props.myparam` is still `1`.

Comment: @Jackyef I would not say that this explains the behavior because for example I tried to use a local variable (instead of `props.myparam`) and change its value through `useEffect()` hook (when the value of `props.myparam` changes) - the result was exactly the same, it does not solve the issue.

Comment: @OtacílioMaia No, removing `props.myparam` from the dependency array doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to myself, as I believe I found the answer.

Instead of using `props.myparam` as a condition in `loop()` function:

```
    if(props.myparam) {                // DOES NOT DETECT PROP CHANGE PROPERLY!!!
      setTimeout(() => loop(), 1000)
    }
```

I use a local variable as a flag:

```
    if(runLoop) {                
      setTimeout(() => loop(), 1000)
    }
```

In `useEffect()` in `ChildComponent` I have this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    if(props.myparam) {
      runLoop = 1;
      loop();
    } else {
      runLoop = 0;
    }
    
    return () => {
      runLoop = 0; // this solves the issue
    }
  }, [props.myparam])
```

Then in the `useEffect()` in `ChildComponent` I add a cleanup function to set `runLoop` to false - the script works as expected.

So my conclusion is that React basically instantiates the component on every render and the variables from previous render will not be updated (unless if they are explicitly updated on cleanup).